# Calculating jQuery UI resizable min & max width in the "resizestart" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am really new to Javascript and I am having a little difficulty knowing my way around.

I am trying to make a jQuery plugin for handling resizing elements using the jQuery UI resizable plugin.

When the user starts to resize the div, I want to carry out some logic to determine the minimum & maximum size I would like them to be able to re-size it to but in the documentations examples this is always declared ahead of time.

Below is my attempt to start this off and then I got a bit lost.  This is first thing in Javascript I am making beyond a simple change of text or color.

```js
$.fn.myresize = function() {
  // add draggable handle only on right
  this.resizable({

    handles: 'e'
  });

  var calculateSizes = function(event, ui) {
    // in reality I am reading several different values to work these value out but for simplicity sake here is just arbitary numbers
    var minWidth = 100;
    var maxWidth = 100 * 3;

    // how do I now set the min & max values for jQuery UI resizable?
  }
  
  // call my function for calculating the min & max width
  this.on("resizestart", calculateSize);

};

$(function() {
  $("#resizable").myresize();
});
```

```css
 #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<h2>Resizable</h2>

<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

(Jsfiddle mirror for mobile users: https://jsfiddle.net/9909zfz0/)

I suppose I could work out the sizes for every element of the page ahead of time but this seems like a lot of overhead when I am only interested in adjacent siblings if they want to resize it.

Some general advice here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a snippet that was setting an option and figured it out.  Here it is.

```js
$.fn.myresize = function() {
  // add draggable handle only on right
  this.resizable({

    handles: 'e'
  });

  var calculateSizes = function(event, ui) {
    // in reality I am reading several different values to work these value out but for simplicity sake here is just arbitary numbers

    // here it is
    ui.element.resizable("option", "minWidth", 100);
    ui.element.resizable("option", "maxWidth", 100 * 3);

  }
  
  // call my function for calculating the min & max width
  this.on("resizestart", calculateSizes);

};

$(function() {
  $("#resizable").myresize();
});
```

```css
 #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<h2>Resizable</h2>

<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```